# Can a Pub Quiz be copyrighted? What about the Final Results spreadsheet?

Tags: copyright

This may seem a bit inane, but I'm having a minor tête-à-tête with a local Quiz Master. Our weekly quiz is 10 rounds of a certain topic with 10 questions per round. Each round is displayed for about 5 minutes on TV screens around the room, answers are handed in and graded, the correct answers are read out loud and then the next round appears.

The QM claims that the questions are copyrighted. Doesn't want people taking pictures of the questions.

The QM also claims that taking pictures of the Final Results Spreadsheet (Team A in 1st place with xx points. Team B in 2nd place with yy points. etc.) is plagiarism.

I think the QM is spouting nonsense. "I don't think that word means what you think it means."

I'd like to rebuke these claims, but can't find anything that references quizzes.

Help?

Answer (score 3):

As for plagiarism, that is not a legal concept, so he can define plagiarism however he wants. It certainly isn't, under any definition I have ever seen on Earth and I have seen many (it has to do with "claiming someone else's work as your own").

As for copyright, a set of questions is (potentially) protected by copyright. If they are copied from somebody else's book of questions, then the book author (or publisher) holds copyright. Let's say that QM invented the questions, such as "What is the Turkish word for Janissary?", "What is the most prominent feature of Jannissary garb?" and so on. Then that set of questions, when put down in fixed form, are protected by copyright, and cannot be copied without permission.

Comment: Thanks! Further question, then. Those questions are hardly "creative," are they? I mean, they are questions about facts. You can't copyright a fact, right? But, you can copyright a question whose answer is a fact? Or a *set* of questions?

And, at what point is any copyright being infringed? At the point that I take a picture? Or at the point that I try to use it in some way?

I have a friend who would love to come to quiz, but is busy on quiz days. Sometimes, I send a picture or two after the quiz is over so she can "play along." Would that be copyright infringement?

Comment: oh, and what about the final results spreadsheet? The content was not exactly *created* by QM. If anyone, it was created by the collective of all the teams participating, no?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva if an answer prompts you to have further questions then correct etiquette for stack exchange sites is to ask them **as** questions - not post them in comments.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva, you're basically veering into the realm of the "modicum of creativity" question, which is really separate.

Comment: @Dale That has not been my experience on Stack Exchange sites. I have often seen back-and-forth between OP and someone who offered an answer. In any case, I'm requesting clarification on the original question and answer - specifically, what is "cannot be copied without permission?" - so it's still relevant to this thread.

Comment: To cut through the procedural/meta issues the short answer is that the threshold of creativity needed to qualify for a copyright is very, very low. Both questions and answers to a pub trivia quiz would clearly qualify as sufficiently creative in that context (you couldn't copyright the fact contained in answer itself, just the fact that this has been determined to be the answer to the question) - as StackExchange illustrates, there are lots of possible correct answers to the same question.

Comment: Thank you, @ohwilleke. But, having accepted that yes, pub quiz questions might be copyrightable, what about copyright infringement? Taking a picture is infringement? Is that also the case when I take a picture of a famous painting at a gallery? Or a sculpture? I can see how pirating a CD is infringement, because I can use the ill-gotten music just like the original, but..... help?